# Sinatra `map` not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to run sinatra behind a proxy, at the url `http://server/project/`, so that `GET http://server/project/foo` goes to `/foo` in the app. My `config.ru` looks like this:

```
map('/project') { run App }
```

I see in the log `"GET /project/ HTTP/1.1" 404`; even though i have a `GET '/'` method defined. It works when run normally (just `run App` without the `map` call). I can't figure out why.

Comment: You can try [Sinatra::Mapping](http://sinatra-mapping.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: Are you using anything like Thin or Unicorn in front? or just sinatra?

Comment: This is most likely a misconfiguration of the proxy.